# Git cannot merge due to untracked working tree

Tags: git, github, version-control

[image]

This is printed when trying to merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the local copy, then you should `git add` and `git commit` it before you merge.

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Adding gitignore file'
```

If you want to replace the local copy, just delete the file.